# subprocess behavior when running script with redirect output

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BIN_FOLDER=bin
SEQ_BIN=some_binary
PROFILE_FOLDER=profiles/
FILENAME=$1

mkdir -p $PROFILE_FOLDER

sudo perf record -g -F 999 $BIN_FOLDER/$SEQ_BIN "${@:2}"
sudo sh -c "perf script -F +pid > $PROFILE_FOLDER/$FILENAME.perf"
sudo rm perf.*
```

When I run this script directly on shell, it works fine and outputs the following as expected:

```
<some_binary output>
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0,025 MB perf.data (6 samples) ]
```

but when I run the exact same command on a python script with `subprocess.run` with `capture_output=True` the `stdout` result becomes the output of the `perf script` command (I assume, because the output is a bunch of binary mess).

I presume it's because of the redirect output happening in the script `>`, although I need the python script to capture the actual output as if it was running normally and the file to be created with the redirect. What can I change to do this? Preferably I don't want to change the script.

Comment: That presumption is very unlikely to have any validity -- `>` just runs `open()` and `fdup2()` syscalls; if those didn't work when called from Python's subprocess module, basically everything would be broken. Much more likely it's a `isatty()`-triggered behavior difference; it's quite common for tools to have safeguards that prevent them from dumping garbage to a terminal that doesn't apply when their stdout/stderr/&c is going to a FIFO.

Comment: Can you provide a standalone [mre] people who aren't you can run?

Comment: (Alternately, if you _do_ really think there's something wrong with invoking redirections from shells started by Python's `subprocess` module, you should be able to create a reproducer for that that doesn't require running a root-only, Linux-only tool... but _seriously_, that would be a common, widely-known issue if it did in fact exist).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That `isatty()` check seems to be the opposite of what's happening. He's getting garbage when he runs the script on a terminal, and not when `subprocess` runs it connected to a pipe.

Comment: Where is that binary garbage coming from in the first place?